# Is there a simple way to retroactively add the \long prefix to a macro's definition?

Tags: macros

According to chapter 20 of the *TeXbook*, a macro that is defined as "long" (by saying `\long` just before `\def\<macroname>`) allows arguments with `\par` tokens (i.e., paragraphs). Suppose I encounter a macro that is *not* "long" (e.g. `\thanks`, the title equivalent of `\footnote`). I want to allow paragraphs in its argument, but not to change the macro's definition in any other way. Obviously, I could look up the meaning and define the macro anew, this time as "long". But is there a simple way to add the `\long` prefix?

Comment: Unfortunately `\long\let\somemacro=\somemacro` doesn't do it. (However, this works well with `\global`). It should be possible to define a macro as long with the same definition of an existing macro (of the same name or not), using a similar technique as `\apptocmd` of `etoolbox`.

Comment: If all that's needed is a `\par` inside `\thanks` it's much easier to say `\endgraf` to do the business. In a non `\long` macro it's exactly the token whose name is `\par` that's disallowed in arguments: TeX doesn't look at its meaning (it wouldn't be able, because expansion is suppressed when scanning an argument).

Comment: @egreg: "TeX doesn't look at it's meaning" that's almost, but not entirely true in an alignment context. `\def\foo#1\bar{}\halign{#\cr\relax\foo\amp\bar\cr}` works, but adding `\let\amp&` before screws up everything.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, but here another mechanism is involved; with `\let\amp&`, TeX sees a `&` at the outer brace level and inserts `\endtemplate` to end the cell. This wouldn't happen with `\def\amp{&}`.

Comment: @egreg: that's right. I just wanted to point out that the `\meaning` is still looked at. Only explicit `\-p-a-r` are detected, but TeX still looks at the meaning for other tokens: outer tokens, `&`, `\cr`, and `\crcr` (only those, I think).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If one is sure that the command to be made `\long` is a macro, this should work

```
\def\longpatch#1{\expandafter\getparts\meaning#1\longpatch
  \begingroup\edef#1{\long\def\noexpand#1\the\toks0 {\the\toks2}}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup#1}}
\def\getparts#1:#2->#3\longpatch{\toks0={#2}\toks2={#3}}
```

From `\def\x#1#2{a#1|#2b\hfil}`, using `\longpatch\x` will use `\meaning\x` that generates

```
macro:#1#2->a#1|#2b\hfil
```

so `\expandafter\getparts\meaning\x\longpatch` will store `#1#2` into `\toks0` and `a#1|#2b\hfil` into `\toks2`. Then we define, with `\edef`, the same `\x` to expand to

```
\endgroup\long\def\x#1#2{a#1|#2b\hfil}
```

but the problem is that what comes after `\x` is just a string of characters all having category code 12 (spaces will have category code 10), even the backslash. We solve the problem by expanding `\x` inside `\scantokens` that rereads the characters as if they were just input from a file. Of course this won't work if the tokens in the definition of `\x` have non ordinary category codes.

(Note: we use `#1` also as scratch macro, so that it won't interfere with other possibly defined macros; it's safe, because its redefinition will disappear when the \endgroup inside `\scantokens` is executed, just before redefining `#1` again.)

Another "solution" is to use `\endgraf` instead of `\par` in the arguments to the non `\long` macro.

Answer (score 14):

You can not retroactively add a `\long` prefix to a definition (as Martin wrote, using `\long\let` does not work).

That leaves redefinition as the only option, and this is always hazardous. If you know exactly how the original macro is defined in terms of expected arguments and you are certain that it does not do any catcode trickery, then there is a possible hack:

```
\newtoks\patchtoks    % helper token register
\def\longpatch#1%     % worker macro
  {\let\myoldmac#1%
   \long\def#1##1{\patchtoks={##1}\myoldmac{\the\patchtoks}}}

\def\a#1{#1}          % original definition

\longpatch\a          % redefition

\a{\TeX\par text}     % test

\bye
```

The trick here is the `\the\patchtoks`: this is a situation in which the appearance of embedded `\par` tokens is ignored.

I'll leave this answer as community wiki, because it is rather ugly and perhaps someone else can improve it.