# Is it possible to have multiple paragraphs inside a multicolumn using xcolor or a replacement?

Tags: tables, color, paragraphs

I am getting information written by users in many lines, paragraphs, and I have to put those inside a table, I would like to know if it is possible to instruct LaTeX to accept paragraphs inside a column or maybe inside a multicolumn?

If I try to process this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5pc}


\newenvironment{rtinformation}{
  \begin{longtable}{|m{7cm}|c|m{7cm}|}
  }
  {
    \hline
  \end{longtable}
}

\newcommand{\rtsingle}[1]{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|p{15cm}|}{#1}\\
}

\newcommand{\rttitlesubsection}[1]{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \bf{#1} } \\
}

\newcommand{\rtrowinfo}[2]{
  \hline
  #1: & & #2 \\
}

\newcommand{\rttitlesection}[1]{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|>{\columncolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}}c|}{ #1 } \\
  %\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ #1 } \\
}


\begin{document}
\begin{rtinformation}
  \rttitlesection{This is my section}
  \rtrowinfo{¿Ha realizado alguna gestión respecto de este predio, ante otra entidad?}{Sí}
  \rttitlesubsection{Descripción de gestión:}
  \rtsingle{
    There are 

    plenty

    of paragraphs, the guilty is [table]xcolor
  }

\end{rtinformation}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! Paragraph ended before \multicolumn was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par
```

It looks like `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` is getting in the middle, is there a replacement for `xcolor` to put some colored rows in a table? If I comment the inclusion of the package and the lines

```
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\columncolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}}c|}{ #1 } \\
\rttitlesection{This is my section}
```

Then LaTeX is able to process many paragraphs. Is there a suitable replacement for `xcolor`?

Comment: Check your input; in your example there's a spurious closed brace after ``\\``. It works for me after deleting it and adding some dummy rows.

Comment: thank you, I'm revisiting the complete code, because I had a macro that used the multicolumn, I'm trying to identify the problem to repost

Comment: Not the ``\\``, but the brace after it! Moreover, recall that you can't use ``\\`` inside the argument to `\multicolumn`, use `\newline` instead.

Comment: I published the complete code and found the problem with xcolor, your comments made me debug it to find the real problem, but still to be solved :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ***NOTE added February 15, 2012***
>   Version 1.0a of `colortbl.sty`, released February 13, 2012, addresses and solves the problem, making the patch superfluous (albeit innocuous).

---

The problem is in `colortbl` that's loaded when you load `xcolor` with the option `table`. This package wrongly redefines `\multicolumn` without the `\long` prefix.

A patch is the following magic trick to be written in the preamble somewhere after loading `xcolor` (or `colortbl`):

```
\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \long\def\noexpand\multicolumn##1##2##3{\the\toks0 }}\x
```

It's clearly a bug of `colortbl`.

### Explanation of the trick

While the simplest thing to do is to copy the definition of `\multicolumn` one finds on lines 121-144 of `colortbl.sty` and adding `\long` in front of `\def`, the above trick accomplishes the same thing and is shorter. Moreover it will work flawlessly even if `colortbl.sty` were modified not only to add `\long`.

We need to know that `\multicolumn` wants three arguments. So we open a group and inside it set the token register `\toks0` to contain the replacement text of `\multicolumn`, by giving it dummy arguments. By the rules of TeX, the `#` symbols are doubled. Then we define `\x` to define `\multicolumn` with the requested `\long` prefix and the stored replacement text. The `\endgroup` will be executed only when `\x` is expanded so the net effect is exactly what we wanted. Before the trick `\show\multicolumn` would show

```
\multicolumn=macro:
#1#2#3->\multispan <...>
```

After it it would show

```
\multicolumn=\long macro:
#1#2#3->\multispan <...>
```

where `<...>` stands for the same token list in both cases.

---

Another similar (but more complicated) trick can be found in [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24277/4427)

```
\def\longpatch#1{\expandafter\getparts\meaning#1\longpatch
  \begingroup\edef#1{\long\def\noexpand#1\the\toks0 {\the\toks2}}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup#1}}
\def\getparts#1:#2->#3\longpatch{\toks0={#2}\toks2={#3}}
\makeatletter
\longpatch\multicolumn
\makeatother
```

(The `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` pair is necessary as `\multicolumn` uses `@`-commnds in its replacement text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You probably are interested in this answer

Comment: sorry I wasn't tracking this site when this was posted, I'll fix the package at source.