# Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, incompatibility, footmisc

There is a [question about nested footnotes with commas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39461), which has some answers. Nested footnotes can be properly numbered, and they can be properly hyperlinked. Remaining problem: [Hyperlinked](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) footnotes are not separated by commas, although the [footmisc package](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) with option `multiple` is used. Minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{Here is a footnote.}\footnote{Here is another footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

While `\textsuperscript{,\,}` between the footnote(mark)s would be possible, I am looking for some automatic solution. (The better, if it would also work for nested footnotes.)

Comment: Section 2 of the `footmisc` manual states very clearly that `footmisc` is incompatible with `hyperref`s `hyperfootnotes` option.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, thus: How to solve this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I see that I come some months to late but I want to present my approach to maybe solve the problem or at least to provide a workaround. The problem at my side is, the approach is so simple so that I can't imagine that there is no other people who had the same idea before. So my question is: Where is the catch in this approach?

To explain the code: I redefine the `footnote`-command and have a look to the following command using `\futurelet`. If the next command is also a `footnote`-command a `,`  is included. What do you think about it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}

\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}

\textheight=3cm
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{First footnote}\footnote{Second footnote}\footnote{Third footnote} Text\footnote{Fourth footnote} Text

\end{document}
```

And this is the output of the given example:
[image: multiple footnotes]

Comment: The `\ifx\footnote\nextToken` could use a `\else\ifx\footnotemark\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi%` (and `\footnoetmark` would be needed to be redefined similar to the redefinition of `\footnote`), but otherwise your solution indeed seems to be the obvious one. (Optional argument for footnotes would be needed, too.) Hyperref could do something like "if package footmisc has been loaded with option multiple, then redefine footnote as done by Holle". +1 for this!

Comment: This is also a Steven but from the future. ;) There apparently were some fixes in the meantime and the behavior now is better. If one loads `footmisc` before `hyperref` the MWE and my own use case work fine. However, when you load them the other way around there is a benign(?) warning `LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed`. If you additionally use a `footnote` in a `minipage` you would get another warning however: `Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line…`. Not sure if it's actually a problem but it was not reported yet and kept me looking for a while.

Comment: @stefanct What do you mean by “If one loads footmisc before hyperref the MWE and my own use case work fine.”? Because, with `footmisc 2022/03/08 v6.0d` and `hyperref 2022-05-17 v7.00q`, the OP's MWE compiles certainly but there's no superscript comma between the footnote marks.

Comment: I was referring to the additional `footmisc` package, the order of the respective `\usepackage` commands and some warnings. I had no problems with the functionality whatsoever IIRC though. If it does not work with 2022's versions anymore then something has changed again, which I cannot test or comment on further, sorry.

Answer (score 15):

As @lockstep notes in the comments section above, the incompatibility between the `footmisc` and `hyperref` packages -- which somehow ends up suppressing the automatic insertion of a raised comma between consecutive footnote marks -- is sadly a fairly well-known phenomenon.

As a workaround, you could set up a macro named, say, `\fnsep` (short for "footnote mark separator") in the preamble:

```
\newcommand\fnsep{\textsuperscript{,}}
```

and then insert this little macro every time you have two consecutive footnotes -- which doesn't happen very often, right? -- as in

```
Text.\footnote{Here is a footnote.}\fnsep\footnote{Here is another footnote.}
```

Comment: To quote the OP: *"I am looking for some automatic solution."* ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: Yeah, an automatic solution seems rather elusive, doesn't it? :-( If a halfway decent automatic solution were known, either the `hyperref` or the `footmisc` package would have incorporated it by now and hence the question wouldn't have to be asked in the first place, right?

Comment: Don't be so pessimistic. It's  like saying *"If there were any easy-to-fix bugs in `colortbl`, they would have been fixed by now."* http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39976/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-paragraphs-inside-a-multicolumn-using-xcolor-or

Comment: @lockstep & Mico: Here at tex.SE some astonishing solutions have been presented, thus I was just so bold as to ask whether there is some solution to the problem. In the footmisc manual is not written "It's not possible" but "Further work on the interaction between the two packages [footmisc & hyperref] is proposed, but not yet scheduled.", which sounds like it could be possible with enough time and knowledge of TeX. Maybe one needs just the right idea, and maybe somebody already had some solution but never published it? Thus I thought: better ask, as the worst case would be no answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Stephen! The sentence you quote from the `footmisc` manual has been in there, AFAICT, more or less unchanged for quite a few years. Alas, to date nobody has risen to the challenge of providing a solution.

Comment: OK, after waiting for over a month, you are obviously right that there is really no known solution at this time. Therefore I accepted your answer now. Maybe/hopefully we will see some solution here (or with an update of either `footmisc` or `hyperref`) in the future.

Comment: @Stephen -- Many thanks! I heartily agree with you that a solution to the odd incompatibility between the two packages would be most welcome.

Comment: After six month, there are now two (!) solutions. To quote my comment: "Here at tex.SE some astonishing solutions have been presented". I *know* it was the right place to ask! Now that there are real solutions, I did accept one of those instead of your answer. Sorry! But I gave a +1 for it.

Comment: @Stephen - Great news indeed! Do you want to take it upon yourself to write to the maintainers of either the footmisc or the hyperref packages to alert them to the existence of a new solution to the old problem?

Comment: Notified the maintainers of hyperref and footmisc.

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility: the `fnpct` package handles multiple footnotes and supports `hyperref` correctly. However, since the main [purpose of the package is a different one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/5049) you might want to use its option `dont-mess-around`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}
 % uncomment if don't want the kerning and punctuation switching:
% \setfnpct{dont-mess-around}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{First footnote}\footnote{Second footnote}\footnote{Third footnote}
Text\footnote{Fourth footnote} Text

\newpage\null%so we see that the hyperlinks are correct
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, that also works with a `\footnotemark` after a `\footnote` - but not with two consecutive `\footnotemark`s. +1 nevertheless!

Comment: I like a package having an option like `dont-mess-around`.

Comment: @DohnJoe Me too :)

Comment: For `\multfootnote` automagic, and for package `babel` using French, see [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-kerning-between-commas-full-stops-and-foo#comment719294_56221)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (slight) improvement of the [(very nice!) solution provided by @Holle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62091/18401)  that takes in account the optional argument of the `\footnote` command (as provided by the LaTeX kernel). It makes use of the `expl3` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCommandCopy{\__old_footnote}{\footnote}
\let\__next_token\relax

\RenewDocumentCommand {\footnote} { O{} m }{
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}{
    \__old_footnote { #2 }
  }{
    \__old_footnote [#1] { #2 }
  }
  \futurelet\__next_token\__next_token_is_footnote:
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__next_token_is_footnote:
{\if_meaning:w\footnote\__next_token\textsuperscript{,}\fi}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\textheight=3cm
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{First footnote}\footnote{Second footnote}\footnote{Third footnote}
Text\footnote{Fourth footnote} Text

Text\footnote[10]{Fifth footnote} Text

\end{document}
```