# Set Latex footnote hanging without using footmisc package

Tags: footnotes, links

I need the same positioning of footnotes marks and text as produced by using `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}` (footnote mark close to the left margin, some space between mark and text and the same space between the text and the left margin for all the lines). I also need to make hyperlinks to the footnotes. Since `footmisc` and `hyperref` packages don't work well together (*i.e.* no hyperlinks to footnotes are produced), is it possible to specify mentioned positioning without using `footmisc` package? Or is there any other way to accomplish both desired positioning and linking?

Here is the working example of what I want to accomplish, just with the working hyperlink:

```
% Compiled using XeLaTeX.
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{report}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]
           {hyperref}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
    \setlength\footnotemargin{12pt}

\begin{document}
\section{This is the title}
    This is some text with the footnote\footnote{And this is the footnote formated
    exactly as I like, but it would be perfect if the hyperlink in the main text
    would work as it does when I do not use the footmisc package.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you load the `hyperref` package *after* the `footmisc` package, you should be getting footnote markers that are hyperlinks to the corresponding footnotes. (Aside: Because `hyperref` has to perform various demanding jobs to convert the cross-reference call-outs, incl. footnote markers, it's important to load it after any package that also affects LaTeX's cross-referencing abilities. The only major exception to this rule is the `cleveref` package: it should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.)

Comment: Thanks, @Mico! It works perfectly! I just wonder why they didn't write this in the `footmisc` package documentation instead of the recommendation to use the `hyperref` package with the option `hyperfootnotes=false`.

Comment: Well, it's sort of common LaTeX lore that certain packages should not be loaded after `hyperref`. I'll write up an answer that makes this all a bit more explicit.

Comment: I know that now. But, as (maybe just a step above) a rookie, I find this part of the `footmisc` documentation misleading. According to them, using `footmisc` and `hyperref` packages is not something that might lead to nicely referenced footnotes. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, IIRC, the main incompatibility between `footmisc` and `hyperref` has to with the former package's option `multiple`: If only `footmisc` is loaded, the `multiple` option works fine, but if the `hyperref` package is loaded as well, the `multiple` option doesn't perform properly. See [Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40072/5001) for more information.

Comment: The recommendation comes from years past, IIRC, when it was true that there were problems with using the two packages together (and, of course, it was likely not considered a big deal since it was assumed that if a reader couldn't find the footnote on his/her own, there were bigger problems than hyperlinking at issue).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your document's footnote markers currently aren't active hyperlinks to the corresponding footnotes because you're loading `footmisc` *after* `hyperref`. If you load `footmisc` *before* `hyperref`, you should get the expected behavior.

Because `hyperref` has to perform various demanding jobs to convert the cross-referencing call-outs, incl. footnote markers, into hyperlinks, it's important to load it *after* most packages that also affect LaTeX's cross-referencing abilities. A major exception to this rule is the `cleveref` package: it must be loaded after `hyperref`.

For more information on which packages should be (or must be) loaded after `hyperref`, see the posting [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5001)

---

*Addendum*: Your claim that the "`footmisc` and `hyperref` packages don't work well together" appears to be based, in part, on a reading of the user guide of the `footmisc` package, which states on p. 7 that

> The `hyperref` package has ambitions to make hyperlinks from footnote marks to the corresponding footnote body; naturally this causes grief to `footmisc`, and unfortunately no remedy is currently known. If you use `footmisc`, suppress `hyperref`'s hyper-footnotes, by loading it as:
>
> `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,...]{hyperref}`

These statements appear to be based on older versions of the two packages. Fortunately, the situation is no longer that bad. In fact, it has been quite good for at least a few years. The only remaining major negative interaction between the two packages that I'm aware of occurs if the `multiple` option of the `footmisc` package is loaded. (If this option is set, LaTeX is supposed to insert a raised comma automatically between consecutive footnote marks.) This option doesn't work if the `hyperref` package is loaded. :-( For more on this vexing topic, see the TeX.SE posting [Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40072/5001).

Answer (score 0):

All footnotes package must be declared after loading `hyperref`, for the hyperlinks to work same goes for `bigfoot`.
When using `tabularx` alongwith with `hyperref`, load `tabularx` after `hyperref`.
I would suggest loading `tabularx` alongwith `hyperref` initially to avoid conflicts as `hyperref` needs to be applied throughout.

Comment: The first claim is clear, but later the question becomes confusing, at least for me. What do you mean? Can you develope?