# Hyperlinked footnote and footcite markers automatically separated by raised commas

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, footnotes, citing

The posting [Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40072/incompatibility-between-footmisc-option-multiple-and-hyperref/62091#62091)
contains a solution to having consecutive footnote markers hyper-linked *and* automatically separated by raised commas.

How to have the same when there is a sequence of footnotes ***and footcites***, such as

```
Text\footnote{First footnote}\footcite{firstcitation}\footnote{citation}
```

This is the solution on the linked page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}

\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}

\textheight=3cm
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{First footnote}\footnote{Second footnote}\footnote{Third footnote} Text\footnote{Fourth footnote} Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your query involves making two additions to [@Holle's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62091/5001) you quoted in your posting.

- First, modify the `\isFootnote` macro to test whether the very next token is either `\footnote` *or* `\footcite` (and, if the test is "true", to instruct LaTeX to insert `\textsuperscript{,}`).
- Second, renew the `\footcite` macro in the same way the `\footnote` macro has been renewed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex} % for '\footcite' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\let\oldFootcite\footcite
\newcommand\nextToken\relax   
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrFootcite}
\renewcommand\footcite[1]{%
    \oldFootcite{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrFootcite}
\newcommand\isFootnoteOrFootcite{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}%
    \else\ifx\footcite\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi%
    \fi}

\setlength\textheight{3cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}

Text.\footnote{First footnote}\footcite{An entry to be cited}\footcite{Another entry to be cited}\footnote{Second footnote}  
More text

\end{document}
```