# How to automatically insert footnote separator in mixed setup with \footnote and \footnoteref and cref

Tags: hyperref, citing, footnotes, cleveref

I have a document with cleveref and hyperref, both of which I don't want to miss. I need to reuse footnotes using cleveref which works fine thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10116. I also want to automatically insert superscript commas between footnotemarks which works fine thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71347. Taken separately, both of them work fine. Combined using code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285630/154602, the footnote is duplicated and formatted incorrectly and the superscript comma is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % must be loaded after hyperref

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10116
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}

%\iffalse % without these lines, footnote marks look fine but miss a comma inbetween
% Inspiration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285630/154602 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71347
\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\let\oldFootnotemark\footnotemark
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrSimilar}
\renewcommand\footnotemark[1]{%
    \oldFootnotemark{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrSimilar}

\newcommand\isFootnoteOrSimilar{%
    \ifx\footnote%
        \nextToken\textsuperscript{,}%
    \else%
        \ifx\footnotemark%
            \nextToken\textsuperscript{,}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}
%\fi

\textheight=7cm
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{First footnote}\footnote{Second footnote}\footnote{Third footnote} Text\footnote{Fourth footnote} Text

Referencing future footnote\cref{second}. Creating a footnote which will be referenced later\footnote{\label{first}First footnote!}

Creating the previously referenced footnote\footnote{\label{second}Second footnote}, and referencing a previously created footnote\cref{first}.

Footnote followed by referenced footnote\cref{first}\footnote{footnote B}

Referenced footnote followed by new footnote\footnote{footnote C}\cref{second}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

How can I make the combination of `\footnote` and `\cref` on a footnote look nice, just as when two `\footnote`s follow each other in the first line of the output?

I think the issue is caused by the fact that when checking `\isFootnoteOrSimilar`, the `\cref` is not expanded. The macro expansion of `\isFootnoteOrSimilar` must be run last, after `\cref` is fully expanded, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The problem arises mainly because of the `\footnotemark` instruction in the argument of `\crefformat`. Please describe in words how call-outs to cross-referenced footnotes should look like.

Comment: call-outs to cross-references should look exactly like "ordinary" footnotes generated using `\footnote{}`, see the first line of the resulting text. I.e. they should be a superscripted hyperlinked number with commas inbetween consecutive call-outs of any footnote type.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the square brackets in the argument of `\crefformat`? Are cross-referenced footnote markers supposed to be surrounded by square brackets? Please advise.

Comment: I do not want to have these square brackets. I put them there by accident. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> call-outs to cross-references should look exactly like "ordinary" footnotes generated using `\footnote`

The following setup may be what you're looking for. Note that you should employ `\cref{<footnote-label>}` if you want to create a cross-reference that consists of both the item's text string (here: `footnote`) and the associated (superscripted) number, and you should use `\labelcref{<footnote-label>}` if you want to create just a superscripted number. In the following example, note the 2 instances of `\cref` and the 3 instances of `\labelcref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\creflabelformat{footnote}{\unskip\textsuperscript{#2#1#3}}

\newcommand\nextToken\relax    
\newcommand\isFootnoteOrSimilar{%
    \ifx\footnote%
        \nextToken\textsuperscript{,}%
    \else%
        \ifx\footnotemark%
            \nextToken\textsuperscript{,}%
    \else%
        \ifx\labelcref%
            \nextToken\textsuperscript{,}%
    \fi\fi\fi%
}

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrSimilar}
\let\oldFootnotemark\footnotemark
\renewcommand\footnotemark[1]{%
    \oldFootnotemark{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrSimilar}
\let\oldlabelcref\labelcref
\renewcommand\labelcref[1]{%
    \oldlabelcref{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnoteOrSimilar}

\textheight=5cm
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

Create a cross-reference to a future \cref{second}. 

Create a footnote which will be referenced later\footnote{\label{first}First footnote}.

Create an already-referenced footnote\footnote{\label{second}Second footnote}.

Create a cross-reference to an already-created \cref{first}.

\medskip
A new footnote mark, followed by a cross-reference to another footnote:
\footnote{Footnote C\label{third}}\labelcref{first}

\medskip
A cross-reference to a footnote, followed by a new footnote mark, followed by a cross-reference to another footnote:
\labelcref{first}\footnote{Footnote D}\labelcref{third}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, thanks for the explanation of `\cref` vs. `\labelcref`.