# What is the "correct" way to have commas between footnotes and prevent footnote superscripts from breaking across lines?

Tags: footnotes

This is what I have done:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
text.\footnote{This is footnote 1}\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 2}\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 3}\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 4}\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 5}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]
[image]

Is there a better way to do this, without having to manually put in the `\textsuperscript{,}`? I'd like it to be automatic.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `footmisc` package with the `multiple` option. See below for a revision of your MWE, for which thank you.

```
% footmarksprob.tex  SE 554074

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
text.\footnote{This is footnote 1}%\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 2}%\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 3}%\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 4}%\textsuperscript{,}%
\footnote{This is footnote 5}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your document doesn't load the `hyperref` package, then adopting the recommendation in [@PeterWilson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554084/5001) -- to load the `footmisc` package with the option `multiple` -- is all you need to do.

If, however, your document does load the `hyperref` package, the aforementioned approach no longer works, i.e., the commas between adjacent footnotes disappear mysteriously. A different approach is required. Specifically, the `footnote` macro needs to be modified along the lines proposed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62091/5001) to the posting [Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40072/5001).

As an alternative to modifying the `\footnote` macro yourself (as is done in the code below), just run

```
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}
```

in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textheight{3cm} % just for this example

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}
\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc} % doesn't hurt, but doesn't work either
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{First}\footnote{Second}\footnote{Third}\footnote{Fourth}\footnote{Fifth}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```