# No paragraph in datatool's DTLforeach possible when using a textblock from textpos

Tags: datatool, textpos

I'd like to print labels using the datatool and the textpos packages.

Yet as soon as I insert a paragraph inside the textbox which is inside the \DTLforeach loop, I get the "Paragraph ended before \DTLifnumeq was complete." error message.

The following example compiles without error:

File testdb.csv:

```
field1,field2,field3
row11,row12,row13
row21,row22,row23
```

File example01.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloadrawdb{testdb}{testdb.csv}

\begin{document}
    \DTLforeach*{testdb}{\addFieldi=field1}{%
        \DTLifnumeq{\DTLcurrentindex}{1}{%
            \begin{textblock}{3}(1,1)
              \addFieldi
              more text.
            \end{textblock}%
        }{}%
    }
\end{document}
```

After inserting a paragraph after the \addFieldi command, the example (called example02.tex) does not compile anymore:

File example02.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloadrawdb{testdb}{testdb.csv}

\begin{document}
    \DTLforeach*{testdb}{\addFieldi=field1}{%
        \DTLifnumeq{\DTLcurrentindex}{1}{%
            \begin{textblock}{3}(1,1)
              \addFieldi

              more text.
            \end{textblock}%
        }{}%
    }
\end{document}
```

I couldn't find a solution on how to circumvent the error.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Use ``\\`` to terminate a line, or `\endgraf`; no empty lines.

Comment: I'd like to use floating text from another file inside the textblocks. I would have to replace all newlines with the \endgraf command. Is there another solution without the need for inserting the \endgraf commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the macro `\DTLifnumeq` doesn't accept `\par` (or empty lines) in its arguments. In TeXnical terms, it is not `\long`. You can modify it adapting the trick I used in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39980/4427):

```
\usepackage{datatool}

\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\DTLifnumeq{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \long\def\noexpand\DTLifnumeq##1##2##3##4{\the\toks0 }}\x

\DTLloadrawdb{testdb}{testdb.csv}
```

Now your macros will be happy with `\par` and empty lines.

---

**TeXnical explanation**
We store in `\toks0` the first level expansion of `\DTLifnumeq` and redefine it as a `\long` macro with the same number of parameters and the same replacement text as the original.