# Calling non-\long macro as \long

Tags: macros

Suppose a given macro is not already `\def`ined `\long`, but I want to call it with `\par`s in the argument.  Is there any way to turn off `TeX`'s error checking for one call?  What I have been doing is roughly

```
\def\short#1{#1}
%\short{a
%
%b}
    %% The commented code above causes an error
\def\aslong{\def\hiddenpar{\par}}
\aslong\short{a\hiddenpar b}
```

This works, in the sense that it produces the desired expansion, but it can hardly be said to be elegant.  I suppose that one could use some cat-code monkeying to achieve a slightly more elegant call syntax, but everything I can think of would become more brittle.

Comment: you can use `\endgraf` rather than `\hiddenpar` which is there for exactly that reason. (at least when `\par` has its normal meaning)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, fair enough, although it still seems inelegant.  Nonetheless, if that's the best possible (i.e., if there is no way to turn off `TeX`'s error checking), then I will accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Can you define a parallel version of the `\short` macro that's "long"?

Comment: the only other way is to extract the definition of \short and redefine another macro that is \long, but that can be tricky if you have delimited macros etc

Comment: @Mico (and DavidCarlisle), indeed, I am trying to use macros whose definition is not in my control, so that it is not trivial to make an identical `\long`'d version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not turn off the error check however plain (and latex) have `\endgraf` which is `\let` (rather than `\def`) to the primitive `\par` and is there for exactly this reason so you can use

```
\short{a\endgraf b}
```

the only other alternative would be to define a `\long` version of the command, which is trivial if copying the source is a possibility, but can be tricky if just the macro is available, especially if it has delimited arguments. If etex is available, basically you can use `\scantokens` to re-parse a `\long\def` that can be constructed from the output from `\meaning\short`.

Comment: Wow, as an old Perl programmer, that `\scantokens` trick makes me think of all the goodness of source filters in that language.  I'll swallow my æsthetic taste and stick with `\endgraf`!

Answer (score 6):

If you have a simple macro, say with two undelimited arguments, it's possible to patch it for becoming `\long` without e-TeX:

```
\def\foo#1#2{#1-#2}

\begingroup\toks0=\expandafter{\foo{#1}{#2}}
\edef\x{\endgroup\long\def\noexpand\foo##1##2{\the\toks0 }}\x

\foo{a\par b}{c\par d}

{\tt\meaning\foo}
```

(see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39980/4427 for an explanation of the trick).

[image]

If the macro has delimited arguments or you don't want to bother knowing how many arguments it takes, `\scantokens` is your friend, but requires an e-TeX enabled engine, such as pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX.

```
\def\makelong#1{%
  \expandafter\getparts\meaning#1\relax
  \domakelong#1%
}

\begingroup
\catcode`M=12 \catcode`A=12 \catcode`C=12 \catcode`R=12 \catcode`O=12
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\getparts#1MACRO:#2->#3\relax}{%
  \def\prefixes{#1}%
  \def\parameters{#2}%
  \def\replacement{#3}%
}

\def\domakelong#1{%
  \edef\temp{\long\prefixes\def\noexpand#1\parameters{\replacement}}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\temp}%
}

\protected\def\short#1{==#1==}
\def\nonlong#1+#2-{(#1)--(#2)}

\makelong\short
\makelong\nonlong

\short{a\par b}

\nonlong X\par Y+Z\par W-

{\tt\meaning\short}

{\tt\meaning\nonlong}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  In fact, your answer that you link makes me wonder if this is a duplicate.  Do you think so?

Comment: @LSpice They are related

Comment: `\scantokens`-technique relies on the same catcode-régime being in effect both at the time of defining the original variant and at the time of re-tokenizing things in terms of `\scantokens`. You may also need to take care of `\newlinechar`, `\endlinechar` and `\escapechar`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using LuaTeX then you can set `\suppresslongerror` to a positive value. For example

```
\def\short#1{#1}

\suppresslongerror=1
\short{a

b}
\suppresslongerror=0
```

or

```
\long\def\forcelong#1{\suppresslongerror=1 #1\suppresslongerror=0 }

\forcelong{\short{a

b}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff I can only offer a `\romannumeral0`-expansion-driven recursive routine `\ReplaceEveryPar`:

```
\ReplaceEveryPar{⟨replacement text⟩}%
                {⟨arbitrary token-sequence where to replace \par⟩}%
```

Each control word token `\par` of the `⟨arbitrary token-sequence where to replace \par⟩` will be replaced by `⟨replacement text⟩`.

You obtain the result after two expansion-steps, i.e., in expansion-contexts you get the result after "hitting" `\ReplaceEveryPar` by two `\expandafter`.

**As a side-effect the routine does replace matching pairs of explicit character tokens of catcode 1 and 2 by matching pairs of curly braces of catcode 1 and 2.**

I suppose this won't be a problem in most situations as usually the curly braces are the only characters of category code 1 / 2...

**In some situations** you can use that routine for replacing every token `\par`, e.g., by `\csname par\endcsname` when having a token-sequence which forms the call to a short macro with `\par` occurring in the short macro's arguments:

With

```
\def\removemacrophrase#1>{}%

\def\MyShortMacro#1#2{%
  \ifvmode\noindent\else\hfil\break\fi
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  Short macro's first argument in parentheses: (\expandafter\removemacrophrase\meaning\tempa)%
  \hfil\break
  \def\tempa{#2}%
  Short macro's second argument in parentheses: (\expandafter\removemacrophrase\meaning\tempa)%
}%
```

the sequence

```
\ReplaceEveryPar{\csname par\endcsname}{%
  \MyShortMacro{A\par B}{C\par D}%
}%
```

yields

```
\MyShortMacro{A\csname par\endcsname B}{C\csname par\endcsname D}%
```

, which in turn yields

```
  \ifvmode\noindent\else\hfil\break\fi
  \def\tempa{A\csname par\endcsname B}%
  Short macro's first argument in parentheses: (\expandafter\removemacrophrase\meaning\tempa)%
  \hfil\break
  \def\tempa{C\csname par\endcsname D}%
  Short macro's second argument in parentheses: (\expandafter\removemacrophrase\meaning\tempa)%
```

**Above I wrote "in some situations" because there are situations where things get tricky:**

**E.g., with (short) macros whose arguments are delimited by the control word token `\par` replacing that control word token should take place with the arguments but not with the argument-delimiters.**

*Things get even worse in case `\par` was let equal to `{` at the time of using `#\par`-notation for definig a macro whose last argument is delimited by a control-word-token `\par` which will get reinserted into the token-stream behind the replacement-text of that macro.*

```
\catcode`\@=11
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange, \UD@removespace
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\long\def\UD@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\UD@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\UD@PassFirstToSecond#1#2{#2{#1}}%
\long\def\UD@Exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherBrace#1{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \UD@firstoftwo}%
  {\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument's first token is an explicit
%% space token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
%%                               space-token>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
%%                               a space-token>}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace#1{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB.#1 }{}}%
}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB#1 {%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#1{}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%
%% The `\romannumeral0-expansion-driven loop in terms of 
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop has 
%%  ( <amount of non-brace-nested \UD@Seldom not occurring as
%%    the very first token within \UD@ExtractFirstArg's 
%%    argument> + 2 )
%% iterations.
%% This implies: Usage of \UD@SelDOm within \UD@ExtractFirstArg's 
%% argument is _not_ forbidden. 
%%.............................................................................
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\long\def\UD@ExtractFirstArg#1{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}%
}%
\long\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check Whether argument which must consist of a single token is the token 
%% \par
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherpar#1#2#3{%
  \UD@@Checkkwhetherparfork#1{#2}\par{#3}\par\par\par
}%
\long\def\UD@@Checkkwhetherparfork#1\par#2#3\par\par\par{#2}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \ReplaceEveryPar{<replacement text>}{<argument where to replace \par>}%
%%
%%   Each control word token \par of the <argument where to replace \par>
%%   will be replaced by <replacement text>.
%%
%%   You obtain the result after two expansion-steps, i.e., 
%%   in expansion-contexts you get the result after "hitting" 
%%   \ReplaceEveryPar by two \expandafter.
%%   
%%   As a side-effect, the routine does replace matching pairs of explicit
%%   character tokens of catcode 1 and 2 by matching pairs of curly braces
%%   of catcode 1 and 2.
%%   I suppose this won't be a problem in most situations as usually the
%%   curly braces are the only characters of category code 1 / 2...
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\ReplaceEveryPar#1#2{%
   \romannumeral0\UD@ReplaceEveryParLoop{#2}{}{#1}%
}%
\long\def\UD@ReplaceEveryParLoop#1#2#3{%
  % #1 = remaining arbitrary token-sequence where to replace \par
  % #2 = token-sequence with replacement applied constructed so far
  % #3 = replacement text
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #2}{%
    \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryParLoop
    \romannumeral0%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#1}{%
       \expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}{#2 }%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral0%
        \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
          \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
          \expandafter{%
            \romannumeral0%
            \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryParLoop
            \romannumeral0%
            \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{}{#3}%
          }{ #2}%
        }{%
          \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherpar
          \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{ #2#3}{%
            \expandafter\UD@Exchange
            \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{ #2}%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
      }%
    }%
    {#3}%
  }%
}%
\catcode`\@=12
%%=============================================================================

\tt\frenchspacing

\ReplaceEveryPar{\Rap}{%
  \def\macro#1{text\par #1 text{\par}}%
}%

\string\macro: \meaning\macro

\bigskip

\def\removemacrophrase#1>{}%

\def\MyShortMacro#1#2{%
  \ifvmode\noindent\else\hfil\break\fi
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  Short macro's first argument in parentheses: (\expandafter\removemacrophrase\meaning\tempa)%
  \hfil\break
  \def\tempa{#2}%
  Short macro's second argument in parentheses: (\expandafter\removemacrophrase\meaning\tempa)%
}%

\ReplaceEveryPar{\csname par\endcsname}{%
  \MyShortMacro{A\par B}{C\par D}%
}%

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the obviously huge amount of work you put into this, but @DavidCarlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250284) of using `\endgraf` accomplished what I needed and can be understood at a glance, so I'll stick with that for now, and keep this one in my back pocket.  Thanks!

Comment: @LSpice   Never mind.  I just put some pieces of code together which I use all the time. That took me only a few minutes. ;-)