# PGF keys error with key filter for keys containing \par

Tags: macros, paragraphs, pgfkeys

I am trying to use `pgfkeys` to store some text for use later. The end goal is to use a key filter to process options first and then apply them to text before it is stored.

In the MWE below, if it try to store text containing `\par`, I get an error when using `pgfkeysfiltered` but not when using `pgfkeys`, which you can see by uncommenting the commented line. I know I am not really using a key filter in the example below, but this is fairly minimal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\storecontent}{}
\newcommand{\usecontent}{\storecontent}

\pgfkeys{%
    /test/temp family/.is family,
    /test/store/.code={\renewcommand{\storecontent}{#1}},
    /test/store/.belongs to family=/test/temp family,
    /pgf/key filters/active families/.install key filter
}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/test/store={first \par test}}

\usecontent

\pgfkeys{/test/temp family/.activate family}
%\pgfkeysfiltered{/test/store={second \par test}}

\usecontent

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can resolve this? Or is this intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some macro used by `\pgfkeysfiltered` is non `\long`, so it doesn't accept arguments containing a `\par` token.

In these cases, assuming a `\par` makes sense (it's up to you to ensure it), you can use the "almost" synonym `\endgraf`. Be careful, however, that in some places LaTeX redefines `\par` but not `\endgraf`.

A different strategy might be to do

```
\newcommand{\notpar}{\par}
```

and using `\notpar` in the problematic place.

---

You can try patching the involved commands; I get no error after these incantations (to be issued after `\usepackage{pgfkeys}`):

```
\makeatletter

\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\pgfkeysfiltered@@install{#1}{#2}}
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \long\def\noexpand\pgfkeysfiltered@@install##1##2{\the\toks0 }}\x

\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke{#1}}
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \long\def\noexpand\pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke##1{\the\toks0 }}\x

\makeatother
```

This makes those macro to accept arguments containing `\par`.

---

As suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24277/4427), also the following way, which is more generic, can work:

```
\def\longpatch#1{\expandafter\getparts\meaning#1\longpatch
  \begingroup\edef#1{\long\def\noexpand#1\the\toks0 {\the\toks2}}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup#1}}
\def\getparts#1:#2->#3\longpatch{\toks0={#2}\toks2={#3}}

\makeatletter
\longpatch\pgfkeysfiltered@@install
\longpatch\pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke
\makeatother
```

How do you find the macros to patch? Well, the error in the original code is

```
! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeysfiltered@@install was complete.
```

So you apply

```
\makeatletter
\longpatch\pgfkeysfiltered@@install
\makeatother
```

(after adding the generic code above). Now you get a similar error

```
! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke was complete.
```

so you know you have to add

```
\longpatch\pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke
```

These must go between `\makeatother` and `\makeatletter`, because the macro have `@` in their name.

Comment: great that was very helpful. i figured something was missing long, but had trouble getting it work work until reading this. my original problem was with `pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke@`, which is in itself a hard command to find in this enormous package.

Comment: Can you see why `\def` is such a disaster? There is a good reason why some commands shouldn't be long. Also, it is not advisable for a user to patch an internal command of a package, except in his/her document or in a local scope.

Comment: @AhmedMusa This is one of the reasons why (non user level) LaTeX3 functions are `\long` by default and one has to explicitly specify `_nopar` if a function must be non `\long`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Re your edit: what makes you think that `\toks0` and `\toks2` are not set locally?

Comment: @egreg: Please see below.

Comment: @AhmedMusa So what? The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are to hide the temporary redefinition of the control sequence with `\edef`. There is no `\global`.

Comment: @egreg: OK, thanks. I always instantiate `\toks0`, `\toks2`, etc., only in local scopes.

Answer (score 3):

TeX has an old feature that macros can be either defined *short*/*normal* or *long*. Only *long* macros may include paragraph breaks, either explicit ones (`\par`) or implicit ones (two sequential line breaks). This was implemented to cause an error quickly if a macro argument was not closed properly, because at this time (1970ties etc.) computing time was expensive. Nowadays it has lost its importance and LaTeX's `\newcommand` defines macros as *long* by default (the starred version doesn't).

Apparently some internal macro in `\pgfkeyfiltered` was not defined as long, so a TeX error is thrown if the content contains `\par`. This is most likely a bug and should be reported to the author of the code. You can workaround this issue by hiding the `\par` from TeX e.g. by using `\csname par\endcsname` or a macro which contains `\par` like `\newcommand\mypar{\par}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on one of egreg's solution. Any command patching scheme that invokes `\scantokens` presumes that the command is scannable. This can't be taken for granted. Hence, command patching should ideally include a test for scannability of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\def\changecmdprefix{\@testopt\ch@ngecmdprefix{}}
\def\ch@ngecmdprefix[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\def\noexpand\getparts####1\detokenize{macro}:####2->####3}%
  \x\changecmdprefix{%
    \scantokens{\endgroup
      \csname @\ifx\@empty#1\@empty first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
      {##1}{#1}\def#2##2{##3}%
    }%
  }%
  \expandafter\getparts\meaning#2\changecmdprefix
}
\changecmdprefix[\long]\pgfkeysfiltered@@install
\changecmdprefix[\protected\long]\pgfkeys@install@filter@and@invoke
\makeatother

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

---

Key filtering using *pgfkeys* seems a complex business. Here is an approach via *skeyval* package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skeyval,xcolor}
\newcommand{\storecontent}{}
\newcommand{\usecontent}{%
  \ifx\storecontent\@empty
    \@@warning{\noexpand\storecontent is empty}%
  \else
    \storecontent
  \fi
}
\def\savpar{\par}
\def\bigvskip{\par\bigskip}
\def\showfam{Family: \skvcurrentfamily\par}

\directkeys{%
  % Define keys in two families:
  .families={family1,family2},
  .define keys={
    .ord/store//\skvappendtomacro\storecontent{#1},
    .ord/remove//\skvpatchcmd\storecontent{#1}{}{}{
      \@@warning{No token '\detokenize{#1}' in command \string\storecontent}
    }
  }
}    
\begin{document}
\directkeys{%
  % Set keys in only family1:
  .family=family1,
  .set keys={
    store={\showfam first test\bigvskip},
    store={\showfam second test\bigvskip}
  },
  .exec code=\usecontent{\color{red}\savpar\hrule\bigvskip},
  % Set keys in only family2:
  .family=family2,
  .set keys={
    remove={\showfam first test\bigvskip},
    remove={\showfam second test\bigvskip},
    store={\showfam third test\bigvskip},
    store={\showfam fourth test\bigvskip}
  },
  .exec code=\usecontent
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other filter handlers include

```
.prefix, .change prefix, .family, .change family, .families, .change families, 
.add family, .add families, .ignore family, .ignore families, .restore family,
.restore families, .paths, .change path, .change paths, .add paths, .ignore paths,
.restore paths, .ignore keys, .restore keys
```