# Fancyhdr and Tikz, runaway argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I am trying to draw some of the headers for a document with TikZ inside a fancy custom header, using the following code:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{aero450}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

    \fancyhead[C]{

        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

            \draw (current bounding box.center) node (__head_c)
                [font=\scriptsize]
            {HEADER HEADER HEADER};

        \end{tikzpicture}

    }
}

\pagestyle{aero450}

\begin{document}
    TEST TEST TEST
\end{document}
```

However, either with xelatex, pdflatex or [writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/645831qtmpxh), I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument? 
{ \begin {tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
Paragraph ended before \f@ncyhf was complete. <to be read again> 
\par l.23 \pagestyle{aero450}
```

What am I doing wrong? writelatex.com says that I might have forgotten a }, but I am pretty sure that I haven't...

Comment: @Werner, have you taken a look at the writelatex example? What did you use for compiling it?

Comment: Your writelatex example doesn't match the code above. Especially it has blank lines inside the `tikzpicture` environment, which is causing the problem.

Comment: You are right @Werner, I deleted one blank line after \begin{tikzpicture}, the one that was causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Werner, so I can remake my question: I cannot add blank lines to the contents of a \chead{}-like command from the fancyhdr package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the blank lines inside your definition of `\fancyhead`. However, this translates to `\fancyfoot`. The reason here is that `\fancyhead` (`\fancyfoot`) - defined using `\newcommand` - calls an internal, universal macro `\f@ncyhf` - defined using `\def` - that stores the header/footer. The former `\newcommand`-created macros accept paragraph breaks (I'll call it `\long`-content), but the latter `\def`-created macro only accepts non-`\long` content. That is, you can't have paragraphs inside them, and since an empty line denotes a paragraph break, it flags an error.

Solution: Remove the blank lines, or use `%` as a line separator if you wish to air out your code.

As reference, see

- [Why don't we always use `\long\def` instead of `\def`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39450/5764)
- [Is there a simple way to retroactively add the `\long` prefix to a macro's definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24240/5764)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Werner. It is quite a tough-to-resolve problem.

Comment: there's an [unouter](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/misc/unouter.tex which removes `\outer` flags from commands.  a similar (possibly even less hair-raising) technique might well work for adding `\long`